# PhantomJS can't open html page with relatively linked script files

Tags: javascript, html, phantomjs

PhantomJS 2.1
I am trying to hook up my tests with phantomjs on teamcity. I would like to set the directory through teamcity, which will put it in some folder on an agent

Here is the code that I am loading:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test!</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>

<body>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"
            integrity="sha256-16cdPddA6VdVInumRGo6IbivbERE8p7CQR3HzTBuELA="
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mocha/3.2.0/mocha.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chai/3.5.0/chai.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="blanket.min.js" data-cover-adapter="mocha-blanket.js" data-cover-reporter="mocha-reporter.js"></script>
    <script data-cover src="../site.js"></script>
    <script src="setup.js"></script>
    <script src="Tests/tests.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

This results in an error:

> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: after
>
> phantomjs://code/suiteAppend.js:1 in global code   :0 in injectJs
>   phantomjs://code/testrunner.js:20
>   phantomjs://platform/webpage.js:286 in _onPageOpenFinished
>   ReferenceError: Can't find variable: run_mocha
>
> undefined:1   :1

If I change the src attributes in the script tags to a hard coded value, everything works as expected.

I've also tried changing the working directory like this:

```
var fs = require("fs");
fs.changeWorkingDirectory("D:/my/folder/to/tests/");
```

How do I use relative linking in a page I'm loading for test?

Thank you for any help.